# Add custom link to top link next to My Account in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, toplinks

this is my config file in etc\module :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
<Net_Toplinks>
  <active>true</active>
  <codePool>local</codePool>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
</Net_Toplinks>
 </modules>
</config>
```

then added this code in app\code\local\net\Toplinks\etc\congif.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Net_Toplinks>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Net_Toplinks>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <net_toplinks>
            <class>Net_Toplinks_Block</class>
        </net_toplinks>
    </blocks>
</global>
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <net_toplinks>
                <file>net_toplinks.xml</file>
            </net_toplinks>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
 </config>
```

Added block file as block\Stores.php

```
<?php 
class Net_Toplinks_Block_Stores  extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
public function addCustomLinks() 
 {  
    $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock(); 
    if ($parentBlock ) 
    {
        $text = 'casa';
        //Top link Display Text
        $url = ‘testmodule’;
        $position = 3;
        $parentBlock->addLink($text, $url , $text, $prepare=true, $urlParams=array(), $position , null, 'class="top-link-testmodule"');
    }
    return $this;
}
} 
?>
```

& finally added this in mycustom-theme folder under \app\design\frontend\net\custom-theme\layout\net_toplinks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <block type="net_toplinks/stores" name="stores_links">
            <action method="addCustomLinks"></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

Still no link is shown in top links. Currently it shows link in Myaccount dropdown.I want link outside dropdown next to or before Account.

[image]

Comment: No.As you can see I have followed different approach.

Comment: Try this way, <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="yourmodule"><label>Your Label</label><url helper="url"/><title>title</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>

Comment: I tried this but not working...it shows new link under account menu only...I want new link next to Accountmenu

Comment: If you are using reference name ="top.links" then it will come under account menu only

Comment: then how can I add link next to My Account option?

Comment: Call this block after link in header.phtml.... after this <a href="#header-account" class="skip-link skip-account">
                <span class="icon"></span>
                <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Account'); ?></span>
            </a>

Comment: I m new to magento.Can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: add this code in your header.phtml then see it will print or not <?php echo $this->addCustomLinks();?>

Comment: but it already shows new link under MYaccount menu.

Comment: You don't want under My account so first check it display or not then will remove there

Comment: I tried to print <?php echo $this->addCustomLinks;?> but nothing is returned.

Comment: You want to url after that my account right

Comment: Kothari I have added image ,please check it.

Comment: Then simple you can use <a> tag right

Comment: how? currently it comes under Account menu in <li> tag.

Comment: add this in your header.phtml<a href="yoururl"> Custom Url </a>

Comment: Is is a proper way? What about the module that I created ? & what If I need to  hide this link for logged in user?

Comment: if you want to follow that also no problem for time consuming you can use this also

Comment: I want to follow that way using module & block.Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49360/discussion-between-user7193478-and-kothari).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49363/discussion-on-question-by-user7193478-add-custom-link-to-top-link-next-to-my-acc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `header.phtml`, replace the below code under `<div class="account-cart-wrapper">`

```
<div class="account-cart-wrapper">
                <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('customer')->getAccountUrl(); ?>" data-target-element="#header-account" class="skip-link skip-account">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Account'); ?></span>
                </a>

                <!-- Custom links-->
                <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('customer')->getAccountUrl(); ?>">
                    <span class="icon"></span>
                    <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Custom Url'); ?></span>
                </a>

                <!-- Cart -->

                <div class="header-minicart">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('minicart_head'); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I just the duplicate the account url choose what ever you want and change the design as well

Comment: IS is correct way? means there is no need to create any module or block?

Comment: No need to create any module for this?

Comment: but this is not the proper way to give static link like this in magento.